# Is there a way to play a list of music in order using Gosu?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, graphics, libgosu

I'm using Gosu (with Ruby version 2.5.5) to make a music player with a GUI, I have a basic player to play one song at a time, but I'm required to tweak the player so I can play one song after the other from this:

```
@song = Gosu::Song.new(music_file)
@song.play(false)
```

I have three songs that need to play and continue to play in order until all songs are done playing.

The problem is that loops will skip past the previous two songs and play the last one.
Trying to copy the code for every song also skips past the first two songs.

I'm stuck on trying to get Gosu to recognize and play the songs in order without skipping the first two as it run.

I appreciate the help.

edit: the loop I used

```
for i in 0..songs.length - 1
        @song = Gosu::Song.new(songs[i])
        @song.play(false)
end
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you edit your question to show more code? Specifically the loop.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the welcome. I've added the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
AUDIO_FILE_TYPES = %w[wav mp3 ogg aif aiff]

def play_songs(path)
  songs = Dir.entries(path).select do |filename|
    AUDIO_FILE_TYPES.include? File.extname(filename).delete('.')
  end

  songs.each do |song|
    playing_song = Gosu::Song.new(song).play
    while playing_song.playing?
      sleep 0.1
    end  
  end
end

play_songs('path/to/song/directory')
```

Comment: Thank you, I've checked my directories but the code can't seem to find my audio files.

Comment: I think `sleep 0.1` could be what I need, but my program keeps crashing when I run it in the loop I have with `while song.playing?` and `sleep 0.1`.
What are your thoughts?

Comment: please post full stack trace errors in your question. are you using correct full path to the audio files?